# How to use JQuery Validation together with JQuery multiselect plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am trying to set some validation rules on a multiselect field. Problem is the validation only works when I deactivate the JQuery multiselect pluggin. See fiddle. Is there a way to make the two work together?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<link  href="http://wowislandcharter.com/roit/script/jquery/multiselect/multiselect.css"
    type="text/css"
    rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<form id="myform">

<select id="symptom" name="symptom" multiple="" size="15" >

    <option value="1">Watery diarrhea</option><option value="2">Abdominal cramps</option><option value="3">Nausea</option><option value="4">Vomiting</option><option value="5">Diarrhea</option><option value="6">Fever</option><option value="7">Bloody Diarrhea</option><option value="8">Cramps</option><option value="9">Facial pallor</option><option value="10">Tea-colored urine</option><option value="11">Abdominal pain</option><option value="12">Jaundice</option><option value="13">Headache</option><option value="14">Stiff neck</option><option value="15">Weakness</option><option value="16">Confusion</option>

</select>

<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>

<script src="http://wowislandcharter.com/roit/script/jquery/multiselect/multiselect.js"></script>

<script>
$("#symptom").multiselect({

    columns:2,
    texts:{placeholder:"SELECT SYMPTOM"}

   })



$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    symptom: {
      required: true,

    }

  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For starters, on a `select`, there is nothing to validate when the first `option` is selected by default.  There needs to be a first `option` like "please choose" that contains a `value=""` attribute.

Comment: jQuery UI Multiselect also hides the default `select` element so you must set the `ignore` option to `[]` so hidden elements are validated.  `ignore: []`

Comment: solution provided in Validating multiselect with jquery validation plugin works